# I have this message on my terminal as soon I opened

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, 18.04, locale

Hi when I open a terminal it says the next error:
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_NUMERIC: cannot change locale (es_VE.UFT-8): No such file or directory

I know that isn't UFT is UTF I alredy fixed, and is cool, but the message still appears, what can i do?

this is what I did to be in this point:

Append the value to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
echo 'export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"' >>~/.bashrc
```

To make it applicable from the current session of bash, source the ~/.bashrc file:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Example: Here i am changing from en_US.UTF-8 to C:

```
$ locale | grep LC_NUMERIC
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"

$ echo 'export LC_NUMERIC="C"' >>~/.bashrc

$ source ~/.bashrc 

$ locale | grep LC_NUMERIC
LC_NUMERIC=C
```

This will change the locale for only the user running the command, for system wide change you need to add the value to `/etc/default/locale`, check the added portion below.

You can also add the value to the systmwide locale file, `/etc/default/locale`, which will be read at start. To put it there:

```
echo 'LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"' | sudo tee -a /etc/default/locale
```

Or

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "LC_NUMERIC=\"en_US.UTF-8\"" >>/etc/default/locale'
```

---

I did that but for es_VE.UFT-8, can someone know how to fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

revert what you have explained you did with `bashrc` and `/etc/default/locale` then try to reconfigure your locale with this :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: When I tried to revert it and type source ~/.bashrc  it says bash: warning: setlocale: LC_NUMERIC: cannot change locale (es_VE.UFT-8). But I didn't type UFT I type UTF, so I don't understand why it keeps saying that?

Comment: you added 1 line in each of the two files. Remove them and reconfigure locales

Comment: You are welcome. Enjoy your Ubuntu experience !